# Logic shared between controllers and views (or components and helpers) in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I've written a helper to help with generating URLs in my CakePHP 2.3 app. Basically it's a wrapper around Cake's built-in functionality, that helps handle routing prefixes, avoids key/value array pairs for common things, etc, to make the code a bit tidier.

The problem is, I need basically all the same functionality for easily generating these URLs from my helper, available in my controllers - for things like loginRedirect, redirecting after edits, etc.

Is there a good solution for sharing logic between Controllers and Views without duplicating code? I understand that in general Views and Controllers shouldn't share code - but there are exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a 'Utility' and create 'Helper' and 'Component' wrappers for that, that can be used inside your Controller and Views, something like the [TextHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html) / [String Utility](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html) combination.

Comment: Any doco on creating your own utilities in the Cook Book? Can't seem to find any...

Comment: Nope, there isn't any. Basically, Utilities are just classes you design yourself. There are no strict conventions for 'Utilities', but I (personally) just find it the cleanest way to share some logic that can be used inside various parts of your application and isn't limited to just a Helper or Controller/Component

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, you can create a new directory called `Utility` in `app/` and then include any file there by just calling `App::uses("MyUtility", "Utility");` from anywhere in your code. The Utility doesn't have to extend anything by default, so this would work as a utility: `Class MyUtility { <rest of code> }`.